# What is the C#/.NET equivalent of BufferedInputStream (in Java)?

Tags: c#, .net, buffering

What is the C# equivalent for the Java BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there's the [`BufferedStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx) class (which wraps an existing stream like in Java), but you don't need to use it as often as you would use the equivalent in Java since most in-built streams in .NET use a certain amount of internal buffering.

Comment: Get it ! But i get en error when i try wrap a NetworkStream in BufferedStream. The error says it can't implicitly convert BufferedStream to a NetworkStream! Any idea

Comment: @Xris: What code are you using for this? You can't wrap simply by casting, if that's what you're doing...

Comment: Here is the code: `networStream1 = new BufferedStream(networkStream1)`

Comment: I'm guessing the static type of `networStream1` is `NetworkStream`? Change it to `Stream` or `BufferedStream` or use a different variable of a compatible type just for the buffered stream.

Comment: You are right! How can i convert or change a `NetworkStream`object to `Stream` object ?

Comment: A `NetworkStream` is already a `Stream` (can be implicitly converted), but it isn't a `BufferedStream`.

Comment: You can find a sample in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx)